# Form returns empty object in nodejs express

Tags: node.js, express, hbs

The form rendered successfully, but the form doesn't return the values as the object. An empty object is returned when why try to fetch the data from the form using console.log(req.body)

Adminjs

```
router.get('/add-product',function(req,res){
  res.render('admin/add-product')
})
router.post('/add-product',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.body);
})
```

add-product.hbs

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2 class="text-center">Add Product</h2>
                <form action="/admin/add-product" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="title" class="form-label">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title">    
                    <label for="price" class="form-label">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" id="price">
                    <label for="description" class="form-label">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" id="description">    
                    <label for="image" class="form-label">Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">    
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I expecting the data from the form returned when I console res.data

Comment: Are you using the body-parser middleware? If not then `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));` and `app.use(express.json());` should help you out.